# Groovy compilation ends with `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Tags: java, maven, groovy, compilation, stack-overflow

I'm using maven with `groovy-eclipse-compiler` (version 2.9.2-01) and even though the build ends OK, I get following output in the console:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ my-project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Using Groovy-Eclipse compiler to compile both Java and Groovy files
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] my-project ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 39.358 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-16T10:05:13+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 71M/1234M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

... some irrelevant info ...

---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.isArray(ClassNode.java:1467)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.correctToGenericsSpecRecurse(GenericsUtils.java:275)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.correctToGenericsSpecRecurse(GenericsUtils.java:316)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.correctToGenericsSpecRecurse(GenericsUtils.java:276)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.correctToGenericsSpecRecurse(GenericsUtils.java:316)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.correctToGenericsSpecRecurse(GenericsUtils.java:276)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.correctToGenericsSpecRecurse(GenericsUtils.java:316)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.correctToGenericsSpecRecurse(GenericsUtils.java:276)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.correctToGenericsSpecRecurse(GenericsUtils.java:316)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.correctToGenericsSpecRecurse(GenericsUtils.java:276)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.correctToGenericsSpecRecurse(GenericsUtils.java:316)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.correctToGenericsSpecRecurse(GenericsUtils.java:276)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.correctToGenericsSpecRecurse(GenericsUtils.java:316)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.correctToGenericsSpecRecurse(GenericsUtils.java:276)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.correctToGenericsSpecRecurse(GenericsUtils.java:316)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.correctToGenericsSpecRecurse(GenericsUtils.java:276)

... this continues on and on ...
```

When I open the groovy files in Idea, I get the same error during the compilation; however, the code analysis doesn't report any errors.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

**EDIT:**

I found out that following class file (`ArraysInListComparator.groovy`) causes the problem (note that it doesn't matter whether a `List` or any other generic class is used)

```
class ArraysInListComparator<T> implements Comparator<List<T[]>> {
    @Override
    int compare(final List<T[]> o1, final List<T[]> o2) {
        return 0
    }
}
```

However, if the generic array is directly in the comparator, it works fine:

```
class ArraysComparator<T> implements Comparator<T[]> {
    @Override
    public int compare(T[] c1, T[] c2) {
        return 0
    }
}
```

When I rewrite these classes as pure java classes (.java files), they are both compiled without any errors.

Comment: Does the compiled artifact work?

Comment: Some of the classes are not compiled. It looks like the `groovy-eclipse-compiler` doesn't properly report an error to the parent maven jvm. As a result the build is just marked as skipped (not unsuccessful).

Answer (score 0):

the error you show is a bug in the generics handling of an older groovy versions. correctToGenericsSpecRecurse is not supposed to iterate endlessly. I am not sure I have seen the error with ClassNode#isArray as entry point before, but I am pretty sure it is essentially the bug I remember. that means it is not likely to be a bug in the groovy-eclipse-compiler. Updating would help then.. or what you did, and have that file in Java. What I cannot answer is why there is a compilation after the compilation.